# Magento 2.3 Merging dl.xml file when installing new extension

Tags: extensions, magento2.3.5

I have Magento 2.3.5 and am trying to install an extension. The quick of it is, how do I merge dl.xml files or add the argument from one to the existing? When copying the argument from one to the existing didn't work and broke the site until reverted to original dl.

I cannot figure out how to add the argument for the one dl to the other and I did not have a "merge" option in the ftp software that I am aware of when uploading the extension package. I am a novice with such things, but the ways I tried to add the argument to the existing dl.xml files all shut down the website until the original was placed back in. I did review the magento 2 doc on dl.xml but it's beyond me.

Much appreciated, happy holidays to everyone.

-Sean

existing dl.xml reads:

and ends after many lines

```
</type>
```

The new dl.xml reads this in total:

Comment: It did not copy over the code I inserted. Sorry about that. The dl.xml file I need to add to existing is:        <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator">
        <plugin name="csrf_validator_skip" type="Auctane\Api\Plugin\CsrfValidatorSkip"/>
    </type>
</config>

Comment: Thank you, Darin! Simple, but effective. Exactly what I needed. Happy new years, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get exactly what your asking.
If the structure is right in your extension and you di.xml file is correct.
Once you run:

```
setup:upgrade

setup:di:compile
```

Your extension will be installed.
No need to merge the dl.xml file manually.
If its beyound installing a extension. I can't help much.